# logger fails if string has hyphen

Tags: linux, string, bash, logging

I am trying to use `logger` to log messages from my script. I use `logger` as shown below:

```
logger -p auth.notice -t "TEST" "$line"
```

If `$line` has some string with hyphen say for example:

```
line="-retries"
```

Then `logger` fails with error:

```
logger: invalid option -- r
usage: logger [-is] [-f file] [-p pri] [-t tag] [-u socket] [ message ... ]
```

Please help me get rid of this error. I have also tried:

```
logger -p auth.notice -t "TEST" "$(echo $line)"
```

Comment: Does a manual run with `line="max\-retries"`eliminate the error message?

Comment: Specifically, the problem is that the argument *begins* with a hyphen; `logger` interprets it as an option like any other argument beginning with a hyphen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double-hyphen always works well:

```
logger -p auth.notice -t "TEST" -- "$line"
                                ^^
```

From `man logger`:

> `--`     End the argument list.  This allows the message to start with a hyphen (`-`).